# How to create a vulnerability scanner ping @everyone? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I had an idea to create a useful team for **server administrators**.
Thanks to this command, the bot shows in which **channels** you can ping **@everyone** **@here**.

Who has any suggestions on how to create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user15517071's answer would work but only if `@everyone` has no `'MENTION_EVERYONE'` permission by default. If you also want to check that, you will need to update your filter.

Check out the code below, I've added plenty of comments:

```js
const textChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter((ch) => ch.type === 'text');
const canEveryoneMention = message.guild.roles.everyone.permissions.has('MENTION_EVERYONE');

const channelsWhereEveryoneCanBeMentioned = textChannels
  .map((channel) => {
    // if there are no overwrites, and everyone can mention @everyone by default
    if (!channel.permissionOverwrites.size && canEveryoneMention)
      return channel;

    // a filter to check if the overwrites allow to mention @everyone
    const overwriteFilter = (overwrite) => {
      // only check if the overwrite belongs to the @everyone role
      if (overwrite.id !== message.guild.id)
        return false;
      // check if MENTION_EVERYONE is allowed
      if (overwrite.allow.has('MENTION_EVERYONE'))
        return true;
      // or it is allowed by default and it's not denied in this overwrite
      if (canEveryoneMention && !overwrite.deny.has('MENTION_EVERYONE'))
        return true;
      // all other cases
      return false;
    };

    const overwrites = channel.permissionOverwrites.filter(overwriteFilter);

    // only return the channel if there are "valid" overwrites
    return overwrites.size > 0 ? channel : null;
  })
  // remove null values
  .filter(Boolean);

const channelList = channelsWhereEveryoneCanBeMentioned.join('\n');

message.channel.send(`People can mention everyone in the following channels:\n${channelList}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the `TextChannel`s in a guild and look for channels where, say, `@everyone` has the `MENTION_EVERYONE` permission, allowing anyone to ping @everyone or @here.

For example, the below code finds all the `TextChannel`s in a guild, then checks if there is a permission overwrite for `@everyone` and then checks if `MENTION_EVERYONE` is explicitly allowed.

```js
const vulnerableChannels = [];
const channels = message.guild.channels.cache.array().filter(channel => channel.type === 'text');
for (const channel of channels) {
    if (channel.permissionOverwrites.filter(overwrite => overwrite.id === message.guild.id && overwrite.allow.has('MENTION_EVERYONE')).array().length > 0) vulnerableChannels.push(channel.id);
}
let output = 'The following channel(s) are vulnerable:\n';
vulnerableChannels.forEach(channel => output = output.concat(` • <#${channel}>\n`));
message.channel.send(output);
```